# Dependency injection - controller factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to understand the sample code from [an article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/understanding-dependency-injection.htm) about dependency injection.

So basically, there's a controller factory with dictionary. Keys are strings, values are functions taking `RequestContext` and returning `IController` object.

```
public class MyControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
{
  private Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>> controllers;

  public MyControllerFactory(ICustomerRepository repository)
  {
    controllers = new Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>>();
    controllers["Home"] = controller => new HomeController(repository);
  }

  public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
  {
    if(controllers.ContainsKey(controllerName))
    {
      return controllers[controllerName](requestContext);
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The line below, AFAIK, adds a function defined with lambda expression (it takes `controller` as argument and returns `new HomeController(repository)`).

```
controllers["Home"] = controller => new HomeController(repository);
```

Now, what's the point of requiring an RequestContext argument (named `controller` above), if the function does nothing with it, because it simply returns `new HomeController(repository)`? What's the goal of passing **any** argument to a function that returns a new object, without using that argument? Or maybe it does, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The Home Controller here does not use the passed in RequestContext paramaters (confusingly named "controller"). The reason it's there is because the dictionary is defined as

```
  private Dictionary<string, Func<RequestContext, IController>> controllers;
```

The `Func<RequestContext, IController>` is a function that needs to return a controller. The Home Controller's factory function doesn't need the request context; it's just a one line function calling `new HomeController(repository)`, but it's entirely possible that a more complicated controller needs the RequestContext in order to be created.

I should add that this tutorial doesn't seem to be the most well written. I wouldn't have added the requirement for the request context in the dictionary if it's not being used.

Answer (score 0):

The function is required to take a parameter in order to match the `Func<RequestContext, IController>` signature.  The lambda `controller => new HomeController(repository)` is ultimately equivalent to the following method:

```
IController function(RequestContext context)
{
    return new HomeController(repository);
}
```

We can see that this matches the signature of the `Func<RequestContext, IController>`: (Taking some liberties, the compiler doesn't actually generate this)

```
delegate IController Function(RequestContext context);
```

Any function that's used as an item in the dictionary must match that signature.

To put it another way, a lambda taking a single parameter is, in this case, a `Func<RequestContext, IController>` which is fundamentally not the same thing as a parameterless lambda, which would be a `Func<IController>`.